# Acceder a rutas de Laravel desde Javascipt

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy usando el paquete `halivert/laravel-js-routes` para acceder a las rutas de laravel desde Javascript, instale el paquete y agregue el codigo a mi webpack.mix.js como lo solicita en el paquete:

```
// se genera el archivo de rutas publico
mix.js("resources/js/routes", "public/js");
```

e importe el archivo dentro de mi app.js y realice un console.log para validar que todo este bien:

```
import { route } from '../routes.js';
console.log(route('admin.dashboard'))
```

funciona de maravilla, pero ¿Como llamo  a la funcion route desde mis archivos Java script externos?

tengo un archivo llamado app-user-list.js que uso para llamar al servidor y extraer un listado de usuarios a una tabla:

```
      ajax: route("admin.hrDashboard"), // Es aqui donde quiero acceder a la funcion con las rutas
      columns: [
        // columns according to JSON
        { data: '' },
        { data: 'full_name' },
        { data: 'role' },
        { data: 'current_plan' },
        { data: 'billing' },
        { data: 'status' },
        { data: '' }
      ],
```

pero al hacerlo este me arroja el error: `jQuery.Deferred exception: route is not defined ReferenceError: route is not defined` no puedo hacer `import {route} from '../js/routes.js'` o `const {route} = require("../../routes")` porque ninguno de los dos se puede ejecutar desde el navegador, entonces como accedo a la funcion desde otros archivos js?

Disculpen si la respuesta parece demasiado obvia, soy muy nuevo en JS

Comment: luego del import del app.js otros javascripts deberían poder acceder al asunto mediante `window.lascosasdelimport` proba un `console.log( route, window.route, document.route )` en app.js y en external.js aver donde cae

Comment: Al usarlo en app.js funciona de maravilla, el problema es al quererlo usar en otros js, arroja Uncaught TypeError: route is not a function

Comment: la idea es que desde app.js expongas `route` como global para el resto de scripts, asi no tenes q hacer el import en todos y cada uno.  esto sucede porque los imports y definiciones de app.js quedan dentro del scope de app.js debido a que el webpack ( laravel mix ) engloba todo en una [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: en `app.js` prueba poner `window.MYAPP = { route }` luego del import y verifica que `MYAPP.route` existe en el script externo

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que uses [Ziggy](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy) es mucho mas practico y facil de usar

Answer (score 0):

Si son pocas rutas yo suelo hacer algo así en una plantilla blade del proyecto que se carge de las primeras.

```
<script>
  R = {}
  R.miRuta1 = '{{ route('mi.ruta.uno) }}'
  R.miRuta2 = '{{ route('mi.ruta.dos) }}'
</script>
```

Así desde cualquier parte de JS puedo acceder a R.miRuta1

Comment: Es que no quiero introducir js directamente en el blade si no usarlo en archivos separados con js puro, actualmente tengo todo el codigo js en el blade para poder acceder a las rutas mediante php pero no es lo ideal, no entiendo porque no funciona

Comment: Solo tienes que poner las rutas en un blade.php y luego desde cualquier JS (cargado después) puedes usar R.miRuta1
Yo lo he usado para rutas y traducciones y luego desde mis mierdas.js usaba mi T.cadenaAtraducir y R.miRuta
Es verdad que no usaba el mix